# Changing lite server to use dist directory

Tags: angular, lite-server

I have set up an Angular 2 project using the starter sample. Code is placed under the apps directory, ts compiles to js in the same structure and lite-server serves files correctly. All works correctly.

I'd like to move the ts output to a dist directory as I don't like js & map files in the same structure (this is pretty common in other environments).

Adding

```
"outDir": "dist"
```

to the tsconfig.json file does cause the ts to be compiled into .js under the dist/app/app directory. Not sure why this adds a second app to the structure.

Through trial and error testing, seems basedir = "./" works for the old structure. Not sure why this works but it does.

Using bs-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  port: 3000,
  server: {
    // old structure, this works
    baseDir: "./"
    // new structure commented out, does not work
    //baseDir: "./dist"
  }
};
```

Have played with this a while but can't get the dist structure to serve files.

Always get a "Cannot GET /" response.

My tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "outDir": "dist"
  }
}
```

Would appreciate if someone could explain my findings and what I am missing.

Comment: can you share your `tsconfig.json` file ?

Comment: @ranakrunal9 Added. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because of your `dist` folder structure like `dist/app/app` may be lite-server is not able to server your files.
So you can try by defining your base path in your `tsconfig.json` as per your folder structure so your `dist` folder will have correct folder structure, not strcture like `dist/app/app` and after it define correct  `server.baseDir` in your `bs-config.js` :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "baseUrl": "./app",
    "outDir": "./dist"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. 

After that tsconfig.json change, the structure under /dist looks correct (an apps folder along with the source structure). 

I have tried the following bs-config.js settings, both yield the same "Cannot GET /" 

`  module.exports = { 
  port: 3000, 
  server: { 
    // does not work 
    //baseDir: "./dist/app" 
    // does not work 
    //baseDir: "./dist" 
  } 
};   `

Comment: Sorry about the formatting of the code. After 10 unsuccessful attempts to format, reading the docs, google search etc. still a mystery how to get linefeeds in the code comment (` only seems to work when used on each line and double-space ENTER or <br/> does not work for me.